# use pdo connection inside php function

Tags: class, function, pdo

I have a database class for pdo access to my db.
Inside the class I have a function :

`public function isSenderIdinDB($id)`

I do in my script:

```
$conn=new Database($credentials);
$id=something;
echo $conn->isSenderIdinDB($id);
```

works fine.
Now I'd like to use a function in my script, like this:

```
echo fn_isSenderIdinDB($id);
```

with:

```
function fn_isSenderIdinDB($id) {
    return $conn->isSenderIdinDB($id);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried with a:

```
global $conn;
```

inside the `fn_isSenderIdinDB` function, as suggested elsewhere on SO, without success.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Nicolas

Comment: It doesn't worked mean, Are you getting some error?

Comment: SORRY: Declaring $conn as global is the solution, I made a typo.  $conn can also be passed to the function as parameter, as suggested by Nikos

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a variable scope issue, you could try passing $conn as a parameter to your function like this.

```
function fn_isSenderIdinDB(&$connObj, $id) {
     return $connObj->isSenderIdinDB($id);
}
```

And then call your function like that :

```
echo fn_isSenderIdinDB($conn, $id);
```

Perhaps it would help if we could see the whole script or the errors your are getting.

Comment: Thanks, Nikos, it works that way, but it doesn't suit my logics. It works with declaring $conn as global inside the function, in fact.